Why hasn't there been an alternative to jet engines yet?
Why do airlines and military jet aircraft still use jet engines after 85 years of the introduction of this technology?
Why hasn't there been a viable alternative to jet engines yet, even though this technology is one of the most complex and unaffordable?

We still use wheels, after being invented thousands of years ago! Why? It is an efficient means to be able to transport something. Over the thousands of years, the wheel has improved a lot though: wood, metal, rubber to composites.
The same is applicable to jet engines, which is a very broad classification of the propulsion system of an aircraft. From Wikipedia, we read:

"the term jet engine typically refers to an internal combustion air-breathing jet engine such as a turbojet, turbofan, ramjet, pulse jet, or scramjet. In general, jet engines are internal combustion engines.

Like the wheel, the "jet engine" has evolved to an efficient propulsion system for specific applications.
We know that the propulsive efficiency increased when we accelerate more mass with little increase in velocity. In the end we try to apply the propulsion system to give us the best overall efficiency for the platform. So, for lower speed applications, a propeller (using a turboshaft engine), medium speed the high or ultra high bypass turbofan engines, for high speeds the low bypass turbofan engines and straight turbojet engines (with possibility to use reheat/afterburner) to ultra high speed applications using ramjet or scramjet propulsion systems.

Source: E. S. Abdelghany, et. al. , 2013, Effect of Bleed air on Performance of Turbofan Engines, 51st AIAA Aerospace Sciences Meeting including the New Horizons Forum and Aerospace Exposition
Based on the application the propulsion system is chosen. Note that years of development and billions of dollars are required to advance the technology. Choosing an optimum bypass ratio from what optimum preliminary design gives us may be unfeasible to develop, or the benefits may be not worth the development investments.
Dr. Epstein has created a very nice overview:

Source: Dr. A.H. Epstein, 2014, Aeropropulsion for commercial aviation in the twenty-first century and research directions needed, AIAA Journal 52(5):901-911
Know that between the lower left and upper right it has taken us propulsion engineers more than 60 years.
Currently, there are no other scalable power sources with a higher power to weight ratio than "jet engines". Why there aren't any is similar to asking why we haven't invented the antigravity machine yet.

Not only that, but the computers running these engines are still using the binary numeral system, which is 345 years old.
There are multiple viable and practically employed alternatives to jet engines:

Turboprops, which are used on nearly all commuter and many regional airliners
Piston engines, used in general aviation
Electric propulsion, useful for very short trips such as training

We might in fact be approaching the end of the jet domination era: with carbon emissions being a concern, multiple airport queues often being longer than the flight itself, and engine developers promising to solve turboprop noise issues with so-called propfans or open rotors, the 5% speed difference isn't worth the extra fuel. And electrics are so much simpler and more reliable than any other drivetrain that they might displace turboprops from GA.
For long-range airliners, jet engines are simply the best technology we currently have, on a balance of power and energy density, reliability, efficiency, and noise levels, in this order.

Also, "jet" is a very broad category. We went from jet engines to turbo jets to low bypass turbo fans to high bypass turbo fans to very high bypass turbofans to – likely pretty soon – open fans. There's ramjets and scramjets, as well as reconfigurable engines like the Olympus and the J-58.

And minor issues in alternatives to overcome, like energy density.

@JörgWMittag broad and fuzzy.  It's fairly arbitrary saying that a turbofan (which gets most of its thrust from the bypass air and some from the core) is in the same category not just as a turbojet but a ramjet while a turboprop (that gets most of its thrust from prop and some from the core) isn't.  Of course the core:bypass ratio is different, as is the gearing, but a difference in numbers of similar magnitude is a small difference compared to presence/absence of major features.
